# iOS App crash on button click

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, automatic-ref-counting

I am creating buttons inside the for loop below shown is the code for that

```
 for(int i=1;i<[_imageDetailsEntities count];i++)
{
    UIButton *bttn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    bttn.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,75,75);
    [_scrollView addSubview:bttn];
    ImageDetails *imageDetails=[_imageDetailsEntities objectAtIndex:i];
    UIImage *image= [self imageFromPath:imageDetails.imagePath];
    [bttn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    bttn.tag=i-1;
    [bttn addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    x=bttn.frame.origin.x+bttn.frame.size.width+distanceBetweenButtons;
    if(i%3==0)
    {
        x=29;
        y=y+bttn.frame.size.height+20;
    }

}
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,y+95)];


-(void)imageTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *bttn=(UIButton*)sender;
    [_delegate didFinishChoosingImageAtIndex:bttn.tag];

 }
```

App is crashing with EXC_Bad access message when i tap a button.I am using ARC. I am not sure, what i am missing here.Please help me

Comment: have you check _delegate . Is is nil ?

Comment: @bit-whacker that is not the problem. He can use void if he add event programatically.

Comment: @Nishnat Tyagi i checked even by commenting that line of code. But still crashes

Comment: Is your imageTapped: method calling ?

Comment: No it is not being called. i checked by keeping breakpoint

Comment: app crashes on which line?Put an exception breakpoint and try

Comment: What is the exception message that is printed when the app crashes?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in logs?

Comment: I checked your code at my end and its working fine. I only commented image section you are using to set on button.

Comment: [_delegate didFinishChoosingImageAtIndex:sender.tag];

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing following line under imageTapped:

```
[_delegate didFinishChoosingImageAtIndex:bttn.tag];
```

with

```
if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didFinishChoosingImageAtIndex:)]){
    [_delegate didFinishChoosingImageAtIndex:bttn.tag];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on [NSZombie](http://cocoa-nut.de/?p=16) and see if something is being released too soon.EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that something was already deallocated when you sent it the message.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your code does exactly, but it looks like your for-loop has a one-off error. 
Either use

```
    for(int i=0;i<[_imageDetailsEntities count];i++)
```

or

```
    for(int i=1;i<=[_imageDetailsEntities count];i++)
```

if you want to iterate over all thingies.

Answer (score -1):

you should maintain an array of the buttons in your controller, so ARC doesnt dealloc them.

In your interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *buttons;
```

Your code:

```
NSMutableArray *buttons = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i=1;i<[_imageDetailsEntities count];i++)
{
   ...your code
   [buttons addObject:bttn];
}

self.buttons = buttons;
```

You could use that array again to remove buttons from the view if need be.

Comment: if you add them to a view they don't get released, because assigning them to a view increases the retaincount.